# Create a view for workflow tasks in form library

Tags: workflow, infopath, forms-library

I have an InfoPath form library that is tied to a customized approval workflow. When a new form is created, the workflow is started and tasks are assigned to SharePoint groups.

What I would like to do is create a view in the form library that will display all forms that have an outstanding task assigned to the logged in user.  Open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have two additional columns with status and assigned to. when the workflows are run, let the fields get populated accordingly. when the tasks are completed, have the workflow to update the status. 
In the form library create a default view filtered with column 'status' as open and column 'Assigned To' to [Me]

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  How do I get the workflow to update the columns?  The only items that the workflow will allow me to update are items from the task list.  I can't seem to access the form library columns.

Comment: Is this OOB Approval workflow? If you can create a workflow in SPD, you will be able to use the Approval workflow, plus update library columns.

Comment: Your suggestion worked.  I was looking in the wrong scope initially.  I have marked your response as solution.  Thanks much for your help!!